# cking a button in one app? Can apps communicate?

Tags: android

*Is there a way to let apps communicate with each other? So is it possible to send data to another app or to trigger a function in the other app by clicking a button in one app?*your text**

*This is a general question about the concept of an app.*

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible using network communications between the devices on which the apps are installed on. Let's suppose there are Device A, a Server, and Device B:

1. Both devices are connected to a server
2. When the user on Device A clicks the button a message is sent to the server
3. The server forward the message to Device B then it is received by the other device
4. Device B receives the message the other app and reads the data of the message and trigger a function based on the data received

If you don't know the other app's source code or how to call the specific function you want to call on the other app then this becomes a harder task to achieve.

Comment: BTW There are other ways to communicate with other devices using serverless communications such as P2P.